# Deserializing an object with a generic type with Jackson

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have a custom Object which uses a generic type:

```
class MyObject <T> {
    int x;
    String y;
    T customObject;
}
```

I am using jackson to serialize and serialize the object. While de-serializing the object, I wanted to know what exactly should I be passing for the type field.

Should it be option 1 or 2?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject obj1 = objectMapper.readValue(jacksonString, MyObject.class); //option 1

MyObject obj1 = objectMapper.readValue(jacksonString, MyObject<T>.class); //option 2
```

I am confused if this is even the correct approach as well.

Comment: It would need to be option 2, as the deserializer doesn't know what class to use for customObject otherwise. Instead of T, you'll need to explicitly declare what class is used for the generic (i.e. `objectMapper.readValue(jacksonString, MyObject<SomeClass>.class`)

Comment: Because Java generics use type erasure, `MyObject.class` and `MyObject<T>.class` are the very same class object.

Comment: Well, option 2 doesn't compile, so it's _definitely_ not that. The most you can get at compile time is `MyObject<?> obj1 = ... MyObject.class);` After that, you'll need to do unchecked casts; you'll probably want to manually check that `customObject` is of the expected type before you do that cast.

Comment: I used something different - MyObject obj1 = mapper.readValue(jacksonString, new TypeReference<MyObject<T>>() {});

That worked, but then when I deserialize it, I get an error that - com.google.gson.internal.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to myObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain your Gson error.  You have an issue that isn't evident in the code that you've posted.

As for how to make this work with Jackson, using the TypeReference as noted in your comment is the correct answer.  However, that won't fix it all the way.  You have a number of options, including Jackson annotations and/or Jackson "mixins".  However, the easiest to way to fix this is probably to add getters and setters to your classes.  Jackson will detect your getters and setters and serialize and deserialize your objects appropriately.

The following code is janky in a number of ways, but it does work.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final MyType myType = new MyType();
        myType.setField1("blah");
        myType.setField2(311);

        final MyObject<MyType> myObj = new MyObject<>();
        myObj.setX(10);
        myObj.setY("why oh why");
        myObj.setCustomObject(myType);

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObj);
        System.out.println(json);

        final TypeReference<MyObject<MyType>> typeRef = new TypeReference<MyObject<MyType>>() {};

        final MyObject<MyType> myObj2 = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
        System.out.println("x: " + myObj2.getX());
        System.out.println("y: " + myObj2.getY());
        System.out.println("customObject:");
        System.out.println("   " + myObj2.getCustomObject().getField1());
        System.out.println("   " + myObj2.getCustomObject().getField2());
    }

    public static class MyType {
        private String field1;
        private int field2;

        public String getField1() { return field1; }
        public void setField1(final String field1) { this.field1 = field1; }

        public int getField2() { return field2; }
        public void setField2(final int field2) { this.field2 = field2; }
    }

    public static class MyObject<T> {
        private int x;
        private String y;
        private T customObject;

        public int getX() { return x; }
        public void setX(final int x) { this.x = x; }

        public String getY() { return y; }
        public void setY(final String y) { this.y = y; }

        public T getCustomObject() { return customObject; }
        public void setCustomObject(final T customObject) { this.customObject = customObject; }
    }
}
```

The output from this is:

```
{"x":10,"y":"why oh why","customObject":{"field1":"blah","field2":311}}
x: 10
y: why oh why
customObject:
   blah
   311
```

Comment: This definitely is helpful. I want to try this out with my own use case. Will accept the answer once I have it tested. But thank you so much!

Comment: Would I need the getters and setters even if I use the @Builder pattern from Lombok?

Comment: Possibly not.  I have no experience with Lombok, but a Google search revealed people doing things that sound like what you want to do.  For example [this page on creating immutable objects with Lombok and Jackson](http://delta46.us/java-immutable-lombok/).  As a matter of style, I generally avoid polluting my POJOs with Jackson annotations, so I would be tempted to try this with [Jackson mixins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations).